# How to get WMS URL from a map embedded in a webpage?

Tags: wms, web-mapping, web-service, url

**Objective**

I am trying to download the images (or the vector files if possible) from a map embedded in the following webpage https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/internet/#/contenido/index.html

[image]

**Context**

To see the layers you need to click Catálogo Mapas [image] and then chose Region, City and layer, for example "XVIII DIRECCION REGIONAL DE ARICA Y PARINACOTA"->"ARICA"->"Predios".

Inspecting the webpage I realized it uses a WMS request, for example: `"https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/services/ui/wmsProxyService/call?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=sii:BR_CART_ARICA_WMS&styles=PREDIOS_WMS_V0&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&comuna=1101&eac=0&eacano=0&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG:3857&bbox=-7825622.9558363445,-2093457.3306744064,-7825317.2023204,-209351.5825612664"`

My first attempt was trying to connect to the WMS from QGIS, but I couldn't figure out the correct URL (there is no documentation either). Secondly, I tried to change the parameters of the request, but the image doesn't show when anything is changed.

**Question**

Any ideas of how to download this layers?
I think the easiest way would be to infer the WMS URL but maybe there are other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL to append request parameters is just:

```
https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/services/ui/wmsProxyService/call?
```

Normally, you would expect a GetCapabilities request to work

like:

```
https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/services/ui/wmsProxyService/call?service=WMS&requst=GetCapabilities&
```

or for specific versions like:

```
https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/services/ui/wmsProxyService/call?service=WMS&requst=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1
```

but neither of these work, so it may be that the service provider has switched these responses off; possibly they weren't intending anybody else to use the service in their own software clients.  Clients like QGIS need a working `GetCapabilities` response to know what they can offer to the user; so I think it's unlikely you'll find anything to work with QGIS.

The service is working though to give images, your example request gives:

[image: GetMap request]

So possibly you can hand crank some requests for your needs by changing the image size (`height=256&width=256&`) and bounding box (`bbox=-7825622.9558363445,-2093457.3306744064,-7825317.2023204,-209351.5825612664&`)

like (bbox=-7825317.2023204,-2093457.3306744064,-7825011.448804455,-209351.5825612664):

[image: changing bounding box]

Comment: thank you @nmtoken ! Just to know, did you try to change the image size or the bounding box? because when I try changing any number I get a white image...

Comment: Without the capabilities response it'll be difficult to determine what's allowed.  Changing bbox does work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/wms-downloader with following parameters:
`https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/services/ui/wmsProxyService/call`

```
{
"service":"WMS",
"request":"GetMap",
"layers":"sii",
"styles":"",
"format":"image%2Fpng",
"transparent":"true",
"version":"1.1.0",
"name":"Cadastre",
"height":"256",
"width":"256",
"srs":"EPSG%3A3857"
}
```